# How to concatenate parameters in story

Tags: automated-tests, jbehave

How to concatenate parameters in story, for example:

```
@When("text {field|link|button} \"$fieldName\" equals \"$value\"")
```

In story file i want use:

```
...
When text "MyField" equals "#{Number} for <Client>"
...
Examples:
|Client|
|MyClient|
```

But does not work, how best practies for concatenate parameters?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but I think the line should be more like "When <object> equals <value>" and then have under Examples |object|value| followed by the object/value pairs to replace.  As a nit-pick, typically the x = y line is more a "Then" or "Given" not a "When" since it should be either a setup line or an evaluation line.  When is more like "When I click x"

Comment: I have a text in label "NumberMyClient + someText + NameMyClient ", and I want to check this text for equality. Two parts of text its parameters,The question was that I want to make a concatenation.

Comment: I could write a check in two steps, Then text "MyField" contains "<NumberClient>" and Then text "MyField" contains "<NameClient>".How to do it in one step?

Comment: Still not clear, but the actual concatenation and comparison would be done in the underlying step code, not in the story file step definition.  Perhaps you mean one step line with two comparisons versus just one, like `Then <labelText> contains <clientNumber> and <clientName>`  Then the underlying Java code might be `Assert(labelText.contains(clientNumber) and labelText.contains(clientName));`

Answer (score 1):

*Partial* replacement of named parameters in parameterized steps is not supported by JBehave yet. There is an open issue [JBEHAVE-1180](https://jbehave.atlassian.net/browse/JBEHAVE-1180) and fix waiting for approvals.

Here is a concise description of the issue.

> Given I have an implemented step:
>
> ```
> @Given("I do something with parameter $parameter") 
> public void doSomething(@Named("parameter") String parameter) 
> {
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> And I have a scenario:
>
> ```
> Scenario: Do something
> Given I do something with parameter foo-<parameterPart>-bar
> Examples:
> |parameterPart|
> |middle|
> ```
>
> Then `parameterPart` should be properly replaced by value from the
>   examples.
>
> And `foo-middle-bar` value should be passed as `parameter` to the step
>   implementation

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can create a method like this:

```
Then value from field: $name contains values $x and $y
```

and check in java code whether $name contains both values or not

```
@When("value from field: $name contains values $x and $y")
public void checkValues( String fieldName, String value1, String value2){
   String fieldValue = .... get value from field
   assertThat( fieldValue.contains( value1 ));
   assertThat( fieldValue.contains( value2 ));
}
```

---

You can also create a more universal method which accepts a list of values separated by a comma:

```
Then value from field: $name contains values from list:value2,1234,57575, some other string with spaces
```

and it's implementation:

```
@When("value from field: $name contains values from list:$list")
public void checkValues( String fieldName, List<String> list){
   String fieldValue = .... get value from field
   for(String s: list){
      assertThat( fieldValue.contains( s ));
   }
}
```

---

You can also use a convenient method from Hamcrest library: [StringContainsInOrder](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/text/StringContainsInOrder.html)

```
@When("value from field: $name contains values from list:$list")
public void checkValues( String fieldName, List<String> list){
   String fieldValue = .... get value from field;
   assertThat( fieldValue, StringContainsInOrder.stringContainsInOrder( list ));
}
```

Comment: This is not what I need, look at the comment above.